# Expression Language Injection vulnerability struts 2.5.13

Tags: java, security, struts, code-injection, ognl

I am using contrast security tool and seeing contrast reporting a vulnerability in my application saying expression language injection error.

I have searched a lot on this, but did not find anything as my version almost latest.

And Contrast is reporting request parameter named as "abc" is injected with something.

Following is the error Contrast Report - Expression Language Injection from "abc" Parameter on "/App/edit.action"

contrast Stack trace is showing something like this which states method in ognl jar -

```
ognl.Ognl.parseExpression(Ognl.java:110)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecute(OgnlUtil.java:397)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:310)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:188)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:175)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter(OgnlValueStack.java:157)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:129)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:137)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:201)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:67)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:133)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:89)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:101)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:142)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:160)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:175)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:121)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:167)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:203)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:196)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.qd.bw.patient.common.web.DeviceDetectionInterceptor.intercept(DeviceDetectionInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:48)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:574)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:79)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:141)
weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
org.owasp.stinger.StingerFilter.doStinger(StingerFilter.java:147)
org.owasp.stinger.StingerFilter.doFilter(StingerFilter.java:93)
weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1686)
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1646)
weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)`enter code here`
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

Comment: It would probably help the community, if you added some relevant code.

Comment: More details will be required. Note that parameter evaluation has lots of things turned off by default; your app's configuration matters.

Comment: @DaveNewton Hi Dave could you please let me know what i can do to turnoff ognl injection in struts.xml, so that contrast do not report the vulnerability expression language injection for ognl

Comment: IIRC most of the configuration is discussed here: https://struts.apache.org/security/#internal-security-mechanism

Comment: @DaveNewton As per struts-default.xml 
OGNL is already excluded as this is already in the file
<constant name="struts.excludedPackageNames" value="java.lang,ognl,javax" />

Do i need to also add this constant to my struts.xml  ?

Answer (score 3):

Contrast Security here. We love seeing questions on StackOverflow!

It sounds like an HTTP request parameter is being fed to the OGNL evaluator by Struts 2. Without any validation or encoding, it is likely possible for an attacker to use this parameter to execute arbitrary code on your server.

This could be our product discovering what has become a publicly known vulnerability (like CVE-2017-5638.) You could paste more details and we could help here, or you can open a ticket by emailing support@contrastsecurity.com.